# Custom API Integration with Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

Objective: I'm building a shopify website. As shopify provides its own API's but what if I want to integrate my custom api's here i.e instead of having to post product to shopify api, what if I want to use my custom API's and render/get all the products from my custom api only.

Is that possible? Is their enough support and documentation from the shopify.

Comment: Why people downvote when someone asks a genuine question. The question is not answered anywhere, I have done research before asking the question. Is this forum not about asking the question? Can anyone enlighten me.

Comment: I agree. @Invincible Do you find the Solution? I'm stuck on same situation, willing to create custom Shopify api for Mobile App? Can we do that or is there any t & c for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes you can build yourself a custom API, but in the end you will need to request information from the Shopify API since the information is there, there is no other way to get them.

So you can have an endpoint that will be custom but it will need to request the information from the Shopify store.

That said if your store all the information into a separate database then you can create a custom API without the need to request information from the Shopify API ( you will still need to make request to populate the database from the Shopify API )

That said there are too many guides how to create REST API server but StackOverflow is not the place to ask for guides. So you are on own there.